# CMake remove added libraries

Tags: cmake

Is there any way to remove a library from the `LINK_LIBRARIES` added by `target_link_libraries` ?

```
target_link_libraries(Project library1 library2)
get_target_property(cur_cflags Project LINK_LIBRARIES)
message(STATUS ${cur_cflags})
# should print library1 and library2
# here I do something to remove library1
get_target_property(cur_cflags Project LINK_LIBRARIES)
message(STATUS ${cur_cflags})
#should print library2 only
```

Thanks

Comment: According to [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/prop_tgt/LINK_LIBRARIES.html) for LINK_LIBRARIES property, you may modify it with [set_property](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/set_property.html).

Answer (score 5):

Check this

```
target_link_libraries(Project PRIVATE library1 library2)
get_target_property(TARGET_LIBRARIES Project LINK_LIBRARIES)
message("Libraries at start")
message(${TARGET_LIBRARIES})
LIST(REMOVE_ITEM TARGET_LIBRARIES library1 )
message("Modified libraries list")
message(${TARGET_LIBRARIES})
set_property(TARGET Project PROPERTY LINK_LIBRARIES  ${TARGET_LIBRARIES} )
get_target_property(TARGET_LIBRARIES2 Project LINK_LIBRARIES)
message("Libraries after change")
message(${TARGET_LIBRARIES2})
```

Comment: Be careful: While this works for removing it from the list of properties, it does not seem to prevent this from getting linked. I removed a library from the list, but it was still linked when the target was built.

Comment: Similarly, adding an additional library to the list will not result in the library getting linked.