# Remove library added with link_libraries()

Tags: cmake

How do I remove libraries added with `link_libraries()`?

Yes, I know I should use `target_link_libraries()`. I can`t because I must link a library to every future target. [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30819041/link-library-to-all-targets-in-cmake-project). The library is CMake built.
This should be invisible to the C++/CMake developer. He should not have to worry about this lib.
Example:

```
add_library(link-to-all a.cpp)
link_libraries(link-to-all)
add_executable(e1 e1.cpp) # with link-to-all
add_executable(e2 e2.cpp) # with link-to-all
unlink_libraries(link-to-all) #does not exist!
add_executable(e3 e3.cpp) # without link-to-all
# all further targets link without link-to-all!
```

In my case link-to-all is a library with implementation for coverage checking functions. It is enabled depending on a configuration option and should be implicitly used for all coming targets. Coverage analysis may be disabled for specific targets, so I want to be able to disable it.

The coverage is enabled by prepending `CMAKE_<LANG>_COMPILE_OBJECT` and disabled by removing the prefix. Afaik this cannot be done target specific, only global for coming targets. So `unlink_libraries()` would be a function that i can call symmetrically.

```
function(enable_coverage)
   prepend_compiler();
   link_libraries(cov);
   # alternative with loosing target information/dependency
   # prepend_system_libs(<path>/libcov.a)
endfunction()
function(disable_coverage)
   reset_compiler();
   unlink_libraries(cov);
   # reset_system_libs()
endfunction()
```

I could use `CMAKE_<LANG>_STANDARD_LIBRARIES`, (and also remove it there) but I would need the `LOCATION` of the library (generator expression: `TARGET`) in there. But I would also lose the interfaces of `link-to-all`. Also, that would probably remove the build dependencies.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49599673/cmake-remove-added-libraries

Comment: I would instead make requirements explicit everywhere. Implicit linking to a library to be linked to all but one is error prone, more complicated than linking directly and lead to error like this.

Comment: [It seems](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Source/cmLinkLibrariesCommand.cxx) that `link_libraries` affects of further targets via `LINK_LIBRARIES` property, so [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49599673/cmake-remove-added-libraries) provided by squareskittles could help in this case too.

Comment: @kuga Thank you for clarifying your problem. If your `link-to-all` library is included based on a configuration option, why not just use a [`BOOL`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html#logical-operators) generator expression based on the setting of the configuration option, to conditionally include the library in the `link_libraries()` call. No need for an if-statement..

Comment: @squareskittles Thanks for this advice. While it does not work the way you propose (its not bases on configuration option), it may work another way. Will try something next week.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While I agree with @Guillaume, I'll combine the suggestions into an answer, as the linked answer is not very clear. As @Tsyvarev confirmed [in the CMake source](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Source/cmLinkLibrariesCommand.cxx#L35), the `link_libraries()` call sets the [`LINK_LIBRARIES`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/LINK_LIBRARIES.html) target property; the `target_link_libraries()` call does the same. While your executable `e3` will initially be set to link with all libraries, you can remove one (or multiple) libraries from the list using a combination of [`get_target_property()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/get_target_property.html) and [`set_property()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set_property.html#command:set_property). Here is an example to demonstrate how:

```
# Library to be linked to all targets.
add_library(link-to-all a.cpp)
# Library to be linked to (almost) all targets.
add_library(link-to-almost-all b.cpp)

link_libraries(link-to-all link-to-almost-all)
# Gets our link-everywhere libraries. Oops!
add_executable(e3 test.cpp)

# Get the LINK_LIBRARIES property for this target.
get_target_property(E3_LINKED_LIBS e3 LINK_LIBRARIES)
message("Libraries linked to e3: ${E3_LINKED_LIBS}")

# Remove one item from the list, and overwrite the previous LINK_LIBRARIES property for e3.
list(REMOVE_ITEM E3_LINKED_LIBS link-to-almost-all)
set_property(TARGET e3 PROPERTY LINK_LIBRARIES ${E3_LINKED_LIBS})

# Verify only one library is now linked.
get_target_property(E3_LINKED_LIBS_NEW e3 LINK_LIBRARIES)
message("Libraries linked to e3: ${E3_LINKED_LIBS_NEW}")
```

The messages printed here confirm the library was removed from the `LINK_LIBRARIES` target property for `e3`:

```
Libraries linked to e3: link-to-all;link-to-almost-all
Libraries linked to e3: link-to-all
```

Comment: I should have asked more clearly. link-to-all should be removed from all coming libraries (implicitly!). Will edit the question.

Comment: If found the property `<LANG>_COMPILER_LAUNCHER`. With this property i can use your suggestion. Thanks. Answer accepted.

Answer (score 1):

As an additonal answer I repeat what I commented on squarekittles answer (for future reference):

You should use the target property [`<LANG>_COMPILER_LAUNCHER`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/LANG_COMPILER_LAUNCHER.html?highlight=compiler_launcher#prop_tgt:%3CLANG%3E_COMPILER_LAUNCHER) instead of [`CMAKE_<LANG>_COMPILE_OBJECT`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LANG_COMPILE_OBJECT.html?highlight=compile_object#variable:CMAKE_%3CLANG%3E_COMPILE_OBJECT). It can be set on target base.